# Why aren't columns hidden (Range().Columns.Hidden ) after OLEDBConnection.Refresh?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to Refresh a Connection and then formatting the table.

The second part alone is working, but with Refresh it doesn't work the way I would expect.
If I use Debug.Print Range("").Columns.Hidden it's true, but i can see the columns in my table.

Do anyone know what's the Problem?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(4).OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
ActiveWorkbook.Connections(4).OLEDBConnection.Refresh

Rows("25:25").RowHeight = 70
Columns("N:AU").Columns.AutoFit
Range("L:O").Columns.Hidden = True
```

Comment: You are hiding columns of the *active* sheet - is that always the sheet you are refreshing?

Comment: Yes, because I'm using a button in this sheet.
If I delete ActiveWorkbook.Connections(4).OLEDBConnection.Refresh it works fine

Comment: I tried with Excel 2013 and it works finde, it seems to be a Bug in Excel 2016 